# multiple mysql tables vs a single table design

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm looking into building a small survey system and i was wondering what would be the best design for the database based on:
Each question can have a certain type of form for submit the answer.

- Checkbox fields
- Radio fields
- input field
- dropdown field

At first i was thinking since i'm using doctrine to create an entity for each type of field and save it into a separate table.
The seconds option i was thinking would be to throw all the answers i set for a question in a single table and have a type field for the question where i tell it in the form of integer what form layout should load.

What do you think guys how should i do this ?

Comment: The second options sounds to me like the better idea. A table for the questions with a flag for the kind of input and a table for the possible answer options.

Comment: u Need 3 easy tables . 1 store an layout `checkbock;checkbock;input;checkbox` .. then u set the values there `1;1;randomtext;0` --- second table u define the layout `checkbox-Code to write to html` --- 3rd table has all the answers `1;1;randominput;1`. that whay when u want to Change "checkboxes" u just have to Change the layout in table 2 and all forms get the update. this way u can use1 simple script to Loop the $Posts and then get all values back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one table Called **Questions_Answer** with entities as the number of options given for the checkboxes,radioField. 
Like **Answer 1, Answer 2**. 
And since the number of answer can vary, u can add the columns, using the `ALTER`
    `TABLE Questions_Answer ADD column_name datatype`